# Rails 3 ActiveRecord where clause where id is set or null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord, Annotation, with two columns: user_id and post_id, which can be null. An annotation with null user_id and post_id are "global" annotations that are applicable to all posts across all users.

I would like to retrieve all annotations associated with a particular user's post AND all global annotations. In MySQL, the SQL command would be

```
select * from annotations where (user_id = 123 and post_id = 456) or (user_id is null and post_id is null)
```

In Rails 3, what is best way to code this as a Annotation.where clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no really great way to use OR sql syntax.  Your best two options are probably to write the where clause yourself using bound parameters:

```
annotations = Annotation.where("(user_id = ? and post_id = ?) OR (user_id is null and post_id is null)").all
```

Or you can dive into [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel) and use that syntax to craft it (check out [asciicast's Arel post](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3)).

**Warning**, everything in the `or` call is psuedocode, no idea how to do 'post_id is null' - you may have to just pass "user_id is null and post_id is null" to `or()`, but my best guess is:

```
annotations = Annotation.arel_table
annotations.where(annotations[:user_id].eq(123).
            and(annotations[:post_id].eq(456)).
            or(annotations[:user_id].eq(nil).and(annotations[:post_id].eq(nil))
```