# Rails 3 Scope - Find users not in a specific group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, many-to-many

Here is my problem (a bit simplified) :

I've got the following models :

```
class User
has_many :group_users
has_many :groups, through: :group_users


class Group
has_many :group_users
has_many :users, through: :group_users


class GroupUser
belongs_to :group
belongs_to :user
scope :belonging_to_group ->(group) {where(group_id = group.id)}
```

I would like to scope users that are not in one specific group, let's say veggies for examples, something that would begin like this :

```
scope :not_in_group, ->(group)
```

I've tried stuffs with having clauses like that:

```
scope :not_in_group, ->(group) {joins(:group_users).merge(::GroupUser.belonging_to_group(group)).group(:title).having('count(group_users.user_id) = 0')
```

but nothing seems to work

**EDIT** : I've got another problem now, you may want to check this if you're calling your scope from an other class' class method : [Rails - Use a class method from a another class method with one attribute of the second class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24188552/rails-use-a-class-method-from-a-another-class-method-with-one-attribute-of-the)

Comment: Is the only requirement to get users not in a particular group? Do you want to get exactly ActiveRecord ORM solution (or it's ok to write some plain sql code inside of your lambda)?

Comment: Nothing seems to work? Do you get any error?

Comment: @twonegatives : I've edited my question, I hope it is clearer now : I want to get all the users that are not veggies, or not football fans, etc...
Pavan trying with the example I gave, I get no result although some users are not in the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** : I realised that it was not working fine if a user had 2 groups, as he would appear as not in both. I believe that MySQL found an other group_users with the user's id and the other group_id.

So I changed to this, which seems to work :

```
scope :not_in_group, ->(group){
  in_group = User.joins(:group_users).where("group_users.group_id = ?", group.id)
  where(arel_table[:id].not_in in_group.map(&:id))
}
```

In two times but working.

**Previous solution** : only works if your user has one group.

Finally I found a solution, I had to pass raw SQL in `joins()` and `where()` as @Himesh suggested me to do. Thanks a lot to you and @lightswitch05 for your help.

Both of your propositions did not select the users without any group, here is a solution that works :

```
  def not_in_group(group)
    joins('LEFT JOIN group_users ON group_users.user_id = users.id').where("group_users.group_id != ? OR group_users.group_id is null", group.id)
  end
```

Found some held there : [Rails 3 ActiveRecord where clause where id is set or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336952/rails-3-activerecord-where-clause-where-id-is-set-or-null)

Answer (score 1):

According to the rails documentation:

> Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes. These methods will still be accessible on the association objects. [source.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments)

```
class User
#...
    # Retrieve all users not in a specific group
    # example: User.not_in_group(Group.find(5))
    def self.not_in_group(group)
        includes(:group_users).where("group_users.group_id != ?", group.id)
    end
end
```

If you are determined to use a scope, here it is:

```
scope :not_in_group, ->(group) {includes(:group_users).where("group_users.group_id != ?", group.id)}
```

Comment: The scope has the advantage that if no results are found, you can chain methods after calling it, but if your class method doesn't return values, success chaining something after calling it. If you want to read more about this read http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/

Comment: @Octopus-Paul are you sure there is a difference between the two? My method doesn't return results - it returns scope of the joins - which will allow more chaining

Comment: Thank you, it works fine, but how could I also get users in no group ?

Comment: @user284130 I just updated the answer to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` via the `includes` statement. [source](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations).

Comment: It looks like it's a little bit more complicated than I thought. When I'm using `join().where()` it's working fine (I get users in other groups), but I always get no content when I use `includes().where()`. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: @user284130 can you please post the two different queries for each method you are trying? (they should be show in the console of your dev server). We could also chat more in the [ROR Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror)

Comment: when `joins().where(!= )` : 

`SELECT users.* FROM users INNER JOIN group_users ON group_users.user_id = users.id WHERE users.type IN ('User') AND (group_users.group_id != 16) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
`

when `includes().where(!=)` : 

 `SELECT DISTINCT users.id FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN group_users ON group_users.user_id = users.id WHERE users.type IN ('User') AND (group_users.group_id != 12) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Comment: I believe this is more a SQL problem : to me the `WHERE users.type IN ('User') AND (group_users.group_id != 12)` part do not select users where `group_users.group_id` is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
scope :not_in_group, -> group_id {joins(:group_users).where('group_users.group_id != ?', group_id)}
```

For left join, try this:

```
scope :not_in_group, -> group_id {joins("left join group_users on users.id = group_users.user_id").where('group_users.group_id != ?', group_id)}
```

Comment: Sorry - it works with ruby 2, and is not rails specific

Comment: @Himesh  I get this error : ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Column 'group_id' in where clause is ambiguous: ...

By the way, if an user does not belongs to any group, will it be returned ?

Comment: Did you try as it is, i have mentioned `group_users.group_id` so it must not be ambiguous

Comment: To get the users that are not part of any group, you will have to modify query to make a left join

Comment: @Himesh You were right, thank you. Now I do I modify query to make a left join ? In my case, there is only one group and I want users that are not in that group. EDIT : actually there could be many groupes in the future.

Comment: I have made edit to answer for left join, just check if it works!!

Comment: @Himesh I get ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Association named 'left join etc.' not found in ...)

Comment: Strange!! As per rails doc, this must work [Check this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)

Comment: Looks like you forgot to capitalize left join.

Comment: Does that make a difference??