# Rails - Use a class method from a another class method with one attribute of the second class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

Here is my problem : 
I have a class method in my User class. I'm calling it from a class method located in my Shop class.

The thing is, the User class method needs the shop's attribute group_id (Group is a third class).

My User class method is not working properly (see [Rails 3 Scope - Find users not in a specific group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186472/rails-3-scope-find-users-not-in-a-specific-group/24186747#24186747)) because it returns nothing although it should return something.

My code currently looks like this :

```
class User
#...
    # Retrieve all users not in a specific group
    # example: User.not_in_group(Group.find(5))
    def self.not_in_group(groupid)
        includes(:group_users).where("group_users.group_id != ?", groupid)
    end
end

class Shop

  belongs_to :group
  attr_accessible :group_id

  def self.get_users_not_in_shop_group
    User
      .not_in_group(:group_id)
  end
```

In my logs I get :

```
...AND (group_users.group_id != 'group_id') ...
```

I believe I should get something like :

```
...AND (group_users.group_id != 13) ...
```

What shall I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, you got a semicolon before name of group_id variable. Thus, group_id is not parsed as a variable, but as a symbol (for clarity, you can think of it as kind of a string).
Second, you should not have get_users_not_in_shop_group as a class-level method as you want to get users not in shop group of some particular shop. You need some object of class Shop to make such a query. 
Here is what you should do with your Shop class

```
class Shop
  def get_users_not_in_shop_group
    User.not_in_group(group_id)
  end
end
```

and here is how your query should like:

```
Shop.find(4).get_users_not_in_shop_group # I assume this shop has group_id attribute set correctly
```

Comment: I get this in my logs : `NameError (undefined local variable or method ``group_id' for #<Class:0x007fd1ca0f8db0>)`

Comment: I added the group as a param of the query on Shop object, like `@shop.get_users_not_in_shop_group(@group)` and changed `def self.get_users_not_in_shop_group` to `def self.get_users_not_in_shop_group(group)` and it works fine. Thanks for the inspiration !

Comment: The thing is, I my querry now looks more like @group.shops.first_scope(first_scope_params).get_users_not_in_shop_group(@group). So whatever is the shop in @group.shops, the class methods sends the same result. I find it a little weird.

Comment: Class method is the method which return the same value disregardless of objects. That is why instance-level method should be used instead. Please take a look at this tutorial: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Answer (score 1):

just like the error message says, `group_id` is not defined.

Right now, you are defining `get_users_not_in_shop_group` on `self`. Which means the function would be called like this: `Shop.get_users_not_in_shop_group` (on the class, not on a object). Since you are making the call on the class - it has no idea what its `group_id` is, because its not fetched from the DB.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
def get_users_not_in_shop_group
  User.not_in_group(group_id)
end
```

This way, the function is on the object, not the class. You would call it by doing something like this:

```
Shop.find(5).get_users_not_in_shop_group
```

Comment: this one looks like kind of a duplicate ;)

Comment: @twonegatives - when I wrote my answer yours only said it looked like a typo

Comment: ah, looks like I updated it while you were typing. Did not realize the problem with class-level method at first glance ;)